# HRTF database used in Resonance

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, audio, 3d, virtual-reality

I am doing a research on 3D audio plugins working on unity for my Master's thesis at Aalto University Finland.

I was wondering if Resonance was using KEMAR hrtf database or something customized?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/discover/concepts

Comment: That doesn't answer my question Raj Sharma. Concepts section introduces basic concepts that gives you that binaural effect. However, it doesn't tell anything about hrtf databases used in Resonance plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Resonance Audio uses custom HRIRs that were derived from [the SADIE database](https://www.york.ac.uk/sadie-project/binaural.html). You can refer to [the corresponding spatial-audio section](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/tree/master/spatial-audio) in [the public spatial-media repo on GitHub](https://github.com/google/spatial-media) for further information and resources.